# How can I resize an AsyncImage within a TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use `AsyncImage` on `TabView`:

```
NavigationStack {
    ProfileView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
}
.tabItem {
    let user = viewModel.user
    
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: user?.photoUrl ?? ""), scale: 3.5) { image in
        image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .cornerRadius(40)
        Text("Profile")
    } placeholder: {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
        Text("Profile")
    }
}
```

The image appears but is not circular:

[image]

Comment: `.clipShape(Circle())`

Comment: @ElTomato I tried but I facing same issue

Comment: Show minimal, reproducible lines of code, and I'll see to it.

Comment: I don't know if that can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a "hack" in my opinion, but you can use the [`Image.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(size:label:opaque:colormode:renderer:)) with a `renderer:` argument, to redraw the image in a circularly-clipped space:

```
TabView {
    Text("Foo")
        .tabItem {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "...")) { image in
                let size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
                Image(size: size) { gc in
                    gc.clip(to: Path(ellipseIn: .init(origin: .zero, size: size)))
                    gc.draw(image, in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
                }
                Text("Profile")
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                Text("Profile")
            }

        }
}
```

Output:

[image]

The image is a bit too close to the text in this case. I found using a size of 40x60 and drawing the image on the 40x40 region at the top makes this better.